# JavaFX: mozilla like tabs

Tags: java, javafx

How to make javafx tabs look like in mozilla browser? I am asking only about form not about color etc. Is it possible? I mean like this :
[image]

Comment: I also don't understand what you think is wrong with this question.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to change the look of default controls is to override the default css. Modena is the default theme for JavaFX-8. [I found a copy of modena.css on Github](https://gist.github.com/maxd/63691840fc372f22f470). There are a lot of child elements -- and thus their css definitions -- according to the tab-pane. Have a look at the css file and search for tab-pane.

It is not possible to make such askew curves with javafx-css. With javafx-css only simple round edges are possible. So if you are fine with simple curves, just play around with `-fx-border-radius` and `-fx-background-radius`.

If your tabs are always of the same size (or do not change to much), make a image and use it as background image (-fx-background-image). You find an example of the background-image version in one of the samples by oracle: download the [java-samples v7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) and have a look in `/javafx-samples-2.2.79/src/DataApp/DataAppClient/src/com/javafx/experiments/dataapp/client/dataapp.css`

If your tabs are flexible in width, things are complicated.

Comment: Well, it's not THAT complicated. Use a image for the right part one for the left part which are both fixed size and one for the middle part that streches horizontally... Furthermore you can create such curves using css via `-fx-shape` property, as long as the aspect ratio of the tab is known&fixed...

Comment: @fabian It would be great if you posted the full solution.

Comment: @PavelKasotov The question is closed though...

Comment: @fabian I know although I totally disagree. That's why I voted to reopen. Lets reopen and solve it in spite of all foes.

Comment: "Use a image for the right part one for the left part..." that's right, but you do not have multiple nodes to apply those images as background by default. That's what makes things complicated